# Upgrading Sharepoint 2007 sp1 to sp2

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-server, upgrade

I want to upgrade our Sharepoint server from SP1 to SP2, as we are trying to upgrade Our Sp 2007 to SP 2013.
Can any one tell me how much downtime it will take to upgrade SP 2007 SP1 to SP2?

Answer (score 2):

their is no easy to calculate the down time for the upgrade, it is multi-factor calculation. Its depend number of server, Amount of Data, Hardware used on server  and gap between the Services pakc, etc.

Check this one http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toddca/archive/2008/08/02/the-zero-downtime-sharepoint-patching-myth.aspx